# Python3 - Same values different ids

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having trouble about understanding id in Python3. I always thought holding same value means pointing to same address until i got output like this :

```
>>> a = 1000
>>> b = 1000
>>> id(a)
140241096743312
>>> id(b)
140241096274640
>>> id(1000)
140241096274800
>>> c = 5
>>> d = 5
>>> id(c)  == id(d)
True
```

Why am i getting different addresses ? What makes 1000 special or different from 5 so that variables point different addresses ?

Comment: An `id(..)` is an identifier for the *object*. Two objects can have the same value, but be different objects...

Comment: Furthermore integers between -8 and 255 are cached. So for these integers the `id`s will - on some interpreters - be the same.

Comment: and what about strings ? why do i get same address when i assign same strings to different variables ?

Comment: Please don't remove the parent [tag:python] tag. Doing so harms discoverability.